# why does maven check for updates when I have specified a version?

Tags: maven

I have trouble understanding, why maven has to check for updates each time we build a project.

The pom has specific version mentioned for each dependency. Once those versions are downloaded to the local repo, then maven can use that local copy to build the project. So why does maven have to check for updates when we build the project each time other than just using the local copy?

a side question.

can a maven artifact be changed after releasing it to a repo under a specific version?

Comment: This may happen for `SNAPSHOT` versions you can mention `-o` for ofline

Comment: so this applies only for SNAPSHOT versions? other artifacts do not get updated?

Comment: You can check that yourself, do you see messages like `Downloading: http://nexus.example.com/.../mymodule/7.4/maven-metadata.xml` for non-SNAPSHOT dependencies when you run maven repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

As per Maven, an artifact mainly can be of two types - a `RELEASE` one and a `SNAPSHOT` one. RELEASE dependency(eg: `1.0.1, 2.3.0` etc) of an artifact is a source of truth. Means 1.0.1 version of a jar (say test.jar) will always be the same always. We will release artifacts to remote repository, whenever the product matures or after a sequence of bug fixes.

On the other hand, a development is on going in a project, then specified its version number as `SNAPSHOT`(eg: `2.0-SNAPSHOT, 1.1-SNAPSHOT` etc).

Say if we specified `test-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` as dependency in our project pom.  If we look at the remote repository (Nexus, archiva etc), we can see that it is not saved as version `2.0-SNAPSHOT` rather it will be saved artifact version as `date-timestamp-buildnumber` format, the date-timestamp at which the artifact was built and uploaded to remote repo. (eg: `test-2.0-20150105082634.jar`)

So when ever the development team does the fix for an issue on a daily basis the updated jar with date timestamp will be in uploaded to the remote repo. So it is necessary for maven to do look up for the latest date timestamp of SNAPSHOT artifacts. Maven does this by `maven-metadata.xml` file in the artifact directory in the repo.

Hope this clarifies your query. Let me know, if you need any clarifications